# Return value as a combination of logic OR

Tags: c

I tried finding it but could not find the solution to this.

I just want to know what does this mean in terms of return value. Does it mean that return value can be any of the 5 values present. Or the return value is all of these 5 numbers

```
static int is_navmsg(int msg)  
{  
          return msg==1019||msg==1020||msg==1044||msg==1045||msg==1046;  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will return `1` if the value of `msg` is `1019` or `1020` or `1044` and so on. Otherwise `0`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic conditional statement.

The rule of OR is if any one of the condition is true return the overall status as true (ignoring rest) and if ALL conditions are false return false.

Ex: if msg = 1044, `msg==1019||msg==1020||msg==1044` will be evaluated to 0||0||1 and 1 is returned.

for msg = 1234, it becomes then `0||0||0||0||0` and 0 will be returned.

Comment: so you mean that if msg is any of the 5 values then it will output 1 otherwise if all conditions are false it will output 0

Answer (score 0):

You will never return a value different from 0 or 1. The logical OR will produce a boolean value being 0 if no of the equalities holds true and 1 if at least one equality is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
msg==1019||msg==1020||msg==1044||msg==1045||msg==1046
   A          B           C         D          E
```

`||` is logical OR operation

`is_navmsg()`  output value is `A OR B OR C OR D OR E`

Answer (score 0):

The function returns a boolean (logical) value. it  will return either 1 (for true) or 0 (for false). 
It will return 1 if the msg is equal to 1019 OR if the msg is equal to 1020  OR if the message is equal to 1044 OR if the message is equal to 1045 OR if the message is equal to 1046. In all other cases it will return 0. 
The operator '||' is the boolean OR operator.